# reloading jsf datatable generated using CRUD on clicking a command button

Tags: jsf

my jsf page

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable id="btable" value="#{ballController.items}" var="item">
         <h:column>
             <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
         </h:column>
         <h:column>
             <h:outputText value="#{item.bname}"/>
         </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

    <h:commandButton action="#{ballCOntroller.items}" value="test">
          <f:ajax execute="@form" render="btable" />
    </h:commandButton> 
</h:form>
```

in my controller, this method is called by ballController.items

```
public DataModel getItems() {
    if (items == null) {
        items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
    }
    return items;
}
```

but upon clicking the button itl give me an error saying:

> serverError: classjavax.faces.el.MethodNotFoundException
>   /app/ball/index.xhtml @40,101 action="#{ballController.items}": Method
>   not found: ballController@a7150b6.items()

my goal is to reload the dataTable on clicking the command button without refreshing the entire page.

*Edited

my whole bean code

```
@ManagedBean(name = "ballController")
@ViewScoped
public class ballController implements Serializable {

    private ball current;
    private DataModel items = null;
    @EJB
    private ballFacade ejbFacade;
    private PaginationHelper pagination;
    private int selectedItemIndex;

    public ballController() {
    }

    public ball getSelected() {
        if (current == null) {
            current = new ball();
            selectedItemIndex = -1;
        }
        return current;
    }

    private ballFacade getFacade() {
        return ejbFacade;
    }

    public PaginationHelper getPagination() {
        if (pagination == null) {
            pagination = new PaginationHelper(10) {
                @Override
                public int getItemsCount() {
                    return getFacade().count();
                }

                @Override
                public DataModel createPageDataModel() {
                    return new ListDataModel(getFacade().findRange(new int[]{getPageFirstItem(), getPageFirstItem() + getPageSize()}));
                }
            };
        }
        return pagination;
    }

    public String prepareList() {
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public String prepareView() {
        current = (ball) getItems().getRowData();
        selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
        return "View";
    }

    public String prepareCreate() {
        current = new ball();
        selectedItemIndex = -1;
        return "index";
    }

    public String create() {
        try {

            getFacade().create(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("ballCreated"));
            return prepareCreate();
//            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String prepareEdit() {
        current = (ball) getItems().getRowData();
        selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
        return "Edit";
    }

    public String update() {
        try {
            getFacade().edit(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("ballUpdated"));
            return "View";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String destroy() {
        current = (ball) getItems().getRowData();
        selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
        performDestroy();
        recreatePagination();
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public String destroyAndView() {
        performDestroy();
        recreateModel();
        updateCurrentItem();
        if (selectedItemIndex >= 0) {
            return "View";
        } else {
            // all items were removed - go back to list
            recreateModel();
            return "List";
        }
    }

    private void performDestroy() {
        try {
            getFacade().remove(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("ballDeleted"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        }
    }

    private void updateCurrentItem() {
        int count = getFacade().count();
        if (selectedItemIndex >= count) {
            // selected index cannot be bigger than number of items:
            selectedItemIndex = count - 1;
            // go to previous page if last page disappeared:
            if (pagination.getPageFirstItem() >= count) {
                pagination.previousPage();
            }
        }
        if (selectedItemIndex >= 0) {
            current = getFacade().findRange(new int[]{selectedItemIndex, selectedItemIndex + 1}).get(0);
        }
    }

    public DataModel getItems() {
        if (items == null) {
            items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
        }
        return items;

    }

    private void recreateModel() {
        items = null;
    }

    private void recreatePagination() {
        pagination = null;
    }

    public String next() {
        getPagination().nextPage();
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public String previous() {
        getPagination().previousPage();
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public SelectItem[] getItemsAvailableSelectMany() {
        return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(ejbFacade.findAll(), false);
    }

    public SelectItem[] getItemsAvailableSelectOne() {
        return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(ejbFacade.findAll(), true);
    }

    @FacesConverter(forClass = ball.class)
    public static class ballControllerConverter implements Converter {

        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
            if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            ballController controller = (ballController) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                    getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "ballController");
            return controller.ejbFacade.find(getKey(value));
        }

        java.lang.Integer getKey(String value) {
            java.lang.Integer key;
            key = Integer.valueOf(value);
            return key;
        }

        String getStringKey(java.lang.Integer value) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            sb.append(value);
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object object) {
            if (object == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (object instanceof ball) {
                ball o = (ball) object;
                return getStringKey(o.getId());
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("object " + object + " is of type " + object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type: " + ball.class.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To reload the table , you just need to use `<f:ajax render="btable" />`

```
<h:commandButton value="test">
      <f:ajax render="btable" />
</h:commandButton>
```

But to to do some action , like adding some data to table you need to point the button to a a proper method

```
<h:commandButton value="test" action="#{ballController.addItem}"">
      <f:ajax render="btable" />
</h:commandButton> 


public void addItem() {
    if (items == null) {
        items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
    }
    items.getWrappedData().add(/*something like new MyObject("one","two")*/);
}
```

Comment: i see, can you give me an example on how to add and item to items? i'm sorry i'm still new to jsf and most of the pages are auto generated using CRUD. I have a simple table with ID and Name

Answer (score 1):

```
serverError: classjavax.faces.el.MethodNotFoundException /app/ball/index.xhtml @40,101 action="#{ballController.items}": Method not found: ballController@a7150b6.items()
```

Is occurring because you are trying to access `getItems` in an incorrect way.

Update your bean code as:

```
public DataModel items() {
    if (items == null) {
        items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
    }
    return items;
}
```

or else change your facelet action EL expression as `action="#{ballCOntroller.getItems}"`.

**EDIT**

You can update your `List` as:

```
public class DataTableBean implements Serializable {

    List<String> dataModelList = new ArrayList<DataModel>();

    public List<DataModel> getDataModelList() {
        return dataTableList;
    }

    public void setDataModelList(List<String> dataModelList) {
         this.dataTableList = dataTableList;
    }

    public void addItems(){

        List<DataModel> tempList = getPagination().createPageDataModel(); // Returns a list of type `List<DataModel>`.

        dataModelList.addAll(tempList);

    }
}
```

Comment: i've changed the action to getItems. now it gives me this error: serverError: class java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: Are you trying to access some `Array` or `List` using `items` ? Can you post your bean code where you are getting this error !

Comment: Update the code as pointed by Daniel. As the `action` attribute of your `commandButton` *must* always return a `String` or an `Object` (the toString() of which is called to derive the logical outcome).

Comment: hmm i don't think im accessing any array or list. the error pops up in the page like a jquery alert();

Comment: @RowiePo Check out the error log and post your bean code where you are getting this error.

Comment: it's weird coz im not getting any error on my error log. btw, the alert error occurs only after i created a data in my ball entity. first i create a data then try to refresh the table, clicking on the button gives me the error, but if i dont create any data and just click the button, no error occurs.

Comment: Try updating your code: public int getItemsCount() {
                    return getFacade().count()-1;
                }

Comment: i added that to the bean but nothing changed